# SQL Server Reporting Services very slow after migration

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

**Updated: Sorry! I may have missled you because of the old description. The problem did not exist right after migration, it started to appear 1 week after the migration**

We recently migrated our database and report server to a new database server and a new report server.

**Configurations Before:**

- Database Server: 2008 Enterprise, DB01/NamedInstance
- Report Server: same server as database server, native mode, database credentials is
  NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE

**Configurations Now:**

- Database Server: 2012 Enterprise, DC01 (default instance, NOT named
  instance)
- Reporting Services: moved to RP01 (native mode), database
  credentials is SQL Account(sa)

The migration is following MSDN migration instructions and works finally (although we had to mannually remove a redunant scale-out deployment server (same name as the old server) to make it work which I think it's SSRS bug).

**1 week after migration**, reports started to run extremely slow on the new report server.

So I did the following analysis:

1. Execute the report in the old report server (database connection of reports points to new database server) and the new report server, the old report server is running fast as before (1 second), but the new report server is running extremely slow (31 second).
2. Execute the stored procedures directly that the report calls, it's very fast as before (50 ms).
3. Diagnostics [ReportServer$Instance].[dbo].[ExecutionLog] database, TimeDataRetrival is 50 ms in old server, but 30050 ms in new server.
4. Run SQL Server Profiler, execute the report in the old server, everything seems fine. execute the report in the new server, something caught my attention. After last event of each batch, it will "hang" (run) for a long time before "Audit Logout" is generated. The sample below actually runs for 10 seconds but all the statements actually run for less than 1 seconds.
5. I suspect that: a). some configuration like account access have been changed without my acknowledgement. b). the new report server is trying to authenticate a user which does not have proper access and "hang" there for seconds before alternative solution.

**Start of profiler output:**

---

Audit Login -- network protocol: TCP/IP
set quoted_identifier on
set arithabort off
set numeric_roundabort off
set ansi_warnings on
set ansi_padding on
set ansi_nulls on
set concat_null_yields_null on
set cursor_close_on_commit off
set implicit_transactions off
set language us_english
set dateformat mdy
set datefirst 7
set transaction isolation level read committed

Report Server       sa                  1440    100 2013-04-16 16:10:14.393     0X2000002838F4010000000000

---

SQL:BatchStarting
                                            declare @BatchID uniqueidentifier

```
                                        set @BatchID = NEWID()

                                        UPDATE [Event] WITH (TABLOCKX)
                                            SET [BatchID] = @BatchID,
                                            [ProcessStart] = GETUTCDATE(),
                                            [ProcessHeartbeat] = GETUTCDATE()
                                        FROM (
                                            SELECT TOP 8 [EventID] FROM [Event] WITH (TABLOCKX) WHERE [ProcessStart] is NULL ORDER BY [TimeEntered]
                                            ) AS t1
                                        WHERE [Event].[EventID] = t1.[EventID]

                                        select top 8
                                            E.[EventID],
                                            E.[EventType],
                                            E.[EventData]
                                        from
                                            [Event] E WITH (TABLOCKX)
                                        where
                                            [BatchID] = @BatchID
                                        ORDER BY [TimeEntered]
```

Report Server       sa                  1440    100 2013-04-16 16:10:14.393

---

SQL:BatchCompleted
                                            declare @BatchID uniqueidentifier

```
                                        set @BatchID = NEWID()

                                        UPDATE [Event] WITH (TABLOCKX)
                                            SET [BatchID] = @BatchID,
                                            [ProcessStart] = GETUTCDATE(),
                                            [ProcessHeartbeat] = GETUTCDATE()
                                        FROM (
                                            SELECT TOP 8 [EventID] FROM [Event] WITH (TABLOCKX) WHERE [ProcessStart] is NULL ORDER BY [TimeEntered]
                                            ) AS t1
                                        WHERE [Event].[EventID] = t1.[EventID]

                                        select top 8
                                            E.[EventID],
                                            E.[EventType],
                                            E.[EventData]
                                        from
                                            [Event] E WITH (TABLOCKX)
                                        where
                                            [BatchID] = @BatchID
                                        ORDER BY [TimeEntered]
                                            Report Server       sa  0   7   0   0   1440    100 2013-04-16 16:10:14.393 2013-04-16 16:10:14.393
```

---

SQL:BatchStarting
                                    declare @BatchID uniqueidentifier

```
                                set @BatchID = newid()

                                UPDATE [Notifications] WITH (TABLOCKX)
                                    SET [BatchID] = @BatchID,
                                    [ProcessStart] = GETUTCDATE(),
                                    [ProcessHeartbeat] = GETUTCDATE()
                                FROM (
                                    SELECT TOP 8  [NotificationID] FROM [Notifications] WITH (TABLOCKX) WHERE ProcessStart is NULL and
                                    (ProcessAfter is NULL or ProcessAfter < GETUTCDATE()) ORDER BY [NotificationEntered]
                                ) AS t1
                                WHERE [Notifications].[NotificationID] = t1.[NotificationID]

                                select top 8
                                        -- Notification data
                                        N.[NotificationID],
                                        N.[SubscriptionID],
                                        N.[ActivationID],
                                        N.[ReportID],
                                        N.[SnapShotDate],
                                        N.[DeliveryExtension],
                                        N.[ExtensionSettings],
                                        N.[Locale],
                                        N.[Parameters],
                                        N.[SubscriptionLastRunTime],
                                        N.[ProcessStart],
                                        N.[NotificationEntered],
                                        N.[Attempt],
                                        N.[IsDataDriven],
                                        SUSER_SNAME(Owner.[Sid]),
                                        Owner.[UserName],
                                        -- Report Data
                                        O.[Path],
                                        N.[ReportZone],
                                        O.[Type],
                                        SD.NtSecDescPrimary,
                                        N.[Version],
                                        Owner.[AuthType]
                                    from 
                                        [Notifications] N with (TABLOCKX) inner join [Catalog] O on O.[ItemID] = N.[ReportID]
                                        inner join [Users] Owner on N.SubscriptionOwnerID = Owner.UserID
                                        left outer join [SecData] SD on O.[PolicyID] = SD.[PolicyID] AND SD.AuthType = Owner.AuthType
                                    where 
                                        N.[BatchID] = @BatchID
                                ORDER BY [NotificationEntered]
```

Report Server       sa                  1440    100 2013-04-16 16:10:14.393

---

SQL:BatchCompleted
                                    declare @BatchID uniqueidentifier

```
                                set @BatchID = newid()

                                UPDATE [Notifications] WITH (TABLOCKX)
                                    SET [BatchID] = @BatchID,
                                    [ProcessStart] = GETUTCDATE(),
                                    [ProcessHeartbeat] = GETUTCDATE()
                                FROM (
                                    SELECT TOP 8  [NotificationID] FROM [Notifications] WITH (TABLOCKX) WHERE ProcessStart is NULL and
                                    (ProcessAfter is NULL or ProcessAfter < GETUTCDATE()) ORDER BY [NotificationEntered]
                                ) AS t1
                                WHERE [Notifications].[NotificationID] = t1.[NotificationID]

                                select top 8
                                        -- Notification data
                                        N.[NotificationID],
                                        N.[SubscriptionID],
                                        N.[ActivationID],
                                        N.[ReportID],
                                        N.[SnapShotDate],
                                        N.[DeliveryExtension],
                                        N.[ExtensionSettings],
                                        N.[Locale],
                                        N.[Parameters],
                                        N.[SubscriptionLastRunTime],
                                        N.[ProcessStart],
                                        N.[NotificationEntered],
                                        N.[Attempt],
                                        N.[IsDataDriven],
                                        SUSER_SNAME(Owner.[Sid]),
                                        Owner.[UserName],
                                        -- Report Data
                                        O.[Path],
                                        N.[ReportZone],
                                        O.[Type],
                                        SD.NtSecDescPrimary,
                                        N.[Version],
                                        Owner.[AuthType]
                                    from 
                                        [Notifications] N with (TABLOCKX) inner join [Catalog] O on O.[ItemID] = N.[ReportID]
                                        inner join [Users] Owner on N.SubscriptionOwnerID = Owner.UserID
                                        left outer join [SecData] SD on O.[PolicyID] = SD.[PolicyID] AND SD.AuthType = Owner.AuthType
                                    where 
                                        N.[BatchID] = @BatchID
                                ORDER BY [NotificationEntered]
```

Report Server       sa  0   7   0   0   1440    100 2013-04-16 16:10:14.393 2013-04-16 16:10:14.393

---

Audit Logout
Report Server       sa  0   3836    6   10140   1440    100 2013-04-16 16:10:14.393 2013-04-16 16:10:24.533

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I figured it out how to solve it. I modified the report file (.rdl) and uploaded to the new report server to overwrite the existing one, it's running fast as expected.

I suspect that because we used database backup/restore to migrate SSRS 2008 to SSRS 2012, and SSRS 2012 did not upgrade the file format automatically, and that caused the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Have you eliminated parameter sniffing from the equation?

> [Fast query runs slow in SSRS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283943/fast-query-runs-slow-in-ssrs)

Try adding matching fake parameters into the sproc and then at the beginning giving them the values passed in by the corresponding parameters.  See if the report runs faster that way.

Comment: 1. the scenario here is the report is not changed, and it runs fine in the old report server, but slow in the new report server. 2. the SP already has local variables to avoid sniffering

Comment: I understood that the report didn't change, every instance of SQL Server can act differently depending on hardware and settings.  Are you saying the server running the SSRS service changed but the server hosting the db did not?

Comment: Did you try adding OPTION(RECOMPILE) or other hints?

Comment: BEFORE: report+db at same server, NOW: report server differs from db server. TESTING: old report server points to new db server, new report server points to new db server. old report server is fast, new report server is slow. I already added recompile option