# SQL Server Reporting Services 2008 to 2012 pdf renders slow

Tags: sql-server, pdf, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, pdf-rendering

I've recently upgraded from SQL Server 2008 R2 to 2012. No issues with any of the databases, but Reporting Services causes me some problems. I have just attached the existing `ReportingServices` and `ReportingServicesTemp` tables, and it all worked fine.

However, I'm using the reports to create PDF files to send to clients, and the rendering time has increased from a few hundred milliseconds to about 30 seconds for each report. Data and processing time are tiny, and the report is a simple one page report.

I read [SQL Server Reporting Services very slow after migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16030633/sql-server-reporting-services-very-slow-after-migration), and have looked at file format differences, but can't see anything I can change - are the formats even different? Editing the file in SSDT doesn't seem to change anything?

Just in case the databases are actually different, I just created fresh `ReportingServices` databases and re-imported my RDL, same thing. 38s for PDF rendering!!

What am I doing wrong? Any ideas?

Thanks...
Andy

Comment: Did you figure it out?