# SSRS reports running slow after upgrade to SSRS 2012 from 2008

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Recently we have upgraded the SQL server from 2008 r2 to 2014 . 
Also we have upgraded the reports from SSRS 2008 to SSRS 2012. 
After upgradation the reports are taking a lot of time to render. Previously reports were taking 3 seconds to render and display, but the same reports in SSRS 2012 are taking 20 seconds. I have found that if remove SSRS expressions for displaying ' - ' instead of NULL it is taking 10 seconds to run and display. Instead of expressions i have used VB code but there is no change. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: rebuild your indexes?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16030633/sql-server-reporting-services-very-slow-after-migration

Comment: Hi,Mitch we rebuild the indexes

Comment: FYI....Instead of clicking the old solution file using new SSRS version, i created one solution file in SSRS 2012 and added the rdl files manually.

Comment: make sure that index and statics are updated.use cache report that save your time.