# SSRS Report is taking too much time while rendering

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am using SSRS report 2008. My report was working fine suddenly he start taking very long while rendering. I check my query that is working fine and responding in 2, 3 sec but report takes up to 7,8 min to render. I have restart my BI tool and restart my machine but still getting same issue. Any idea how I can fix it? I search a lot from google but didn't found any suitable answer which can solve my problem.

Comment: How are you getting the data to your report?, are you using a stored procedure?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fast query runs slow in SSRS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283943/fast-query-runs-slow-in-ssrs)

Answer (score 0):

Try rendering it in a different web browser.  I'm assuming you are talking about when it is deployed to the server?

Also, sometimes there is an issue with the grouping of the data.  So you might want to play around with the keep together and pagebreak options, for the report under the tablix member properties.

Comment: I have not deployed yet.

Comment: Some things I've tried inlcude: 
1. Taking out the Order By and Sorting using SSRS instead of script.
2. Taking out filters and instead putting parameters into the query itself.
3. Making rows and columns as small as possible so the report has to generate less pages.