# Why is parameter sniffing happening now so that fast query runs slow in SSRS?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

We have an `SSRS report` that uses a `stored procedure` with several parameters. Until this morning, the report ran as usual.

So today I modify the stored procedure and run the `SSRS report`. After the changes, the query runs fast but the `SSRS report` takes several minutes to display the data.

I ended up declaring variables inside the SP instead of using the parameters (as suggested in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283943/fast-query-runs-slow-in-ssrs)) and that fixed the issue.

My question is: what changed that the SSRS report takes much longer to generate data? I understand `parameter sniffing`, but why would it change today? `Parameter sniffing` should be occurring all the time, not today after the the SP was modified.

Comment: Posting the code for your SP is going to considerably help here

Comment: Parameter sniffing **does** happen all the time. It is that today it started to become a performance issue.

Comment: @Larnu: The SP is 300 lines long, so I won't be able to post it. Besides, there's nothing wrong with it.

Comment: It most generally starts to become a performance issue when the data is skewed such that for one parameter a certain execution plan makes sense, but for another value a different execution plan would make sense. Gail Shaw has a great series on the topic here. https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2007/11/27/parameter-sniffing/ The behavior you are experiencing is very much in line with common challenges of parameter sniffing.

Comment: Do you use OPTION RECOMPILE?