# How to find report execution log for visual studio preview of report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am working on an existing SSRS report. It works when viewed in a browser from the report server (~ 30 seconds load), but loads for quite a while in visual studio preview (~ 10 minutes). The queries themselves are fast, so something about the report specifically is causing the slowdown.

As for what I have tried so far, I tried deleting the cached .data file (no fix), deploying the report (works fine when deployed), recreating the data sources, as well as attempting to avoid bad query plans from parameter sniffing (see [Fast query runs slow in SSRS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283943/fast-query-runs-slow-in-ssrs)). None of these fix the problem. The problem only happens specifically when using local preview.

Many articles describe viewing the execution log to figure out what stage the report is taking so much time in (query, data processing, rendering). I would like to do this so I can narrow down the cause, but it works fine on the report server, just not on the local preview. How can I get the equivalent execution log when running local preview, given there is no report database?

I suspect that because forcing the query plans to recompile doesn't solve the problem, and because the report works fine with the same query against the same server when deployed, that the actual problem might be some weird rendering bug. I have heard this can happen with certain pagination settings, but I want to confirm what general area this problem is in.