# SSRS report runs slow, but sql code runs fast

Tags: t-sql, ssms, ssrs-2012

I have a query that takes about 5 seconds to run in ssms but 10 minutes in ssrs.

There are 5 parameters on the ssrs that are running simple queries to pull the parameter results. Each of those queries take less than a second to run. They also depend on each other. For example, you would fill out the supervisor parameter first. Based on what you what supervisors you selected, the employees parameter would prepoulate based on the staff of the supervisors. This filters down to several levels from team, supervisor, employee etc.

How can I reconfigure my parameters to perform more efficiently? I have tried passing the variables into a stored procedure, based on some other posts, but that hasnt had any noticable effects

Comment: would you please add some examples, codes or pictures?

Comment: Did you try solution posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283943/fast-query-runs-slow-in-ssrs ?